# Making a select for a two select sql/oracle

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join join 2 select in single query :

Here are the two queries.

```
        SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
     FROM (
      SELECT id_p1 player_id, score_p1 score
        FROM matchs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id_p2, score_p2
        FROM matchs
      ) q
      GROUP BY player_id
```

AND

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
    FROM (
      SELECT id_p1 player_id, score_p2 score
        FROM matchs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id_p2, score_p1
        FROM matchs
    ) q
     GROUP BY player_id
```

Thank you !

Comment: See CASE... WHEN... THEN... END

Comment: create view for each union query and try to join

Comment: JOIN or MERGE them? Can you please explain with a short example?

Comment: The queries you've provided can't be run. You cannot `UNION ALL` between a query that selects three column and a query that selects two.

Comment: I want to join this 2 select because the first query show all goals that the 1st team scored and the second query show all goals that the 2nd team scored to 1st team

Comment: There are not more than 2 columns,those are aliases.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3575d/5

Comment: I must create an column ? WHat is the problem ? Why there are an duplication of ID's?

Comment: You tagged your question with `mysql` yet your subject says `oracle`. Which of the two is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT table1.player_id, table1.score score1, table2.score score2,
       abs(table1.score - table2.score) difference
FROM (
       SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
       FROM (
              SELECT player1_id player_id, score_p1 score FROM matchs
              UNION ALL
              SELECT player2_id , score_p2 FROM matchs
             ) q GROUP BY player_id
      ) table1
INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
            FROM (
                   SELECT player1_id player_id, score_p2 score FROM matchs
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT player2_id , score_p1 FROM matchs
                  ) q GROUP BY player_id
          ) table2 ON table1.player_id = table2.player_id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49375/10)**

Comment: @Upendra I have this error : #1052 - Column 'player_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @user3149518 : Check my updated answer with demo link

Comment: It's the solution ! Thank you very much @Upendra

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari If I want to made the difference (-) between score1 and score2 (. What is the query for you?

Comment: @user3149518 : Then simple add one column with score1 - score2. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, one would perform this operation using a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT      COALESCE(t1.player1_id, t2.player2_id)
            SUM(COALESCE(t1.score_p1,0) + COALESCE(t2.score_p2,0))
FROM        table_name t1
  FULL JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.player1_id = t2.player2_id
GROUP BY    COALESCE(t1.player1_id, t2.player2_id)
```

However, sadly MySQL does not have native support for such a join operation.  Instead, one can simulate it by making a `UNION` between a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`, then aggregating:

```
SELECT p, SUM(s) FROM (

  SELECT       t1.player1_id p, SUM(t1.score_p1 + IFNULL(t2.score_p2,0)) s
  FROM         table_name t1
    LEFT JOIN  table_name t2 ON t1.player1_id = t2.player2_id
  GROUP BY     t1.player1_id

  UNION

  SELECT       t2.player2_id, SUM(IFNULL(t1.score_p1,0) + t2.score_p2)
  FROM         table_name t1
    RIGHT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.player1_id = t2.player2_id
  GROUP BY     t2.player2_id

) t GROUP BY p
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3575d/51/0).